# How can I set the default branch name for all new projects on GitLab, as an user without admin right over entire instance?

Tags: git, configuration, gitlab

Note that I am not looking to change it for a specific repo.

I want to change the default branch name per account, so any new created repository will have this as default branch.

Currently the default is 'main', some time ago it was 'master'.

See [Set default name for default branch in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109146/set-default-name-for-default-branch-in-github) for a GitHub equivalent.

I found https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/ which is not mentioning such configuration, so it may be not existing at all.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/default.html has an option for an individual repo ("To update the default branch name for an individual project"), there is option for the entire instance or group ("GitLab administrators can configure").

I see nothing that would allow change for a given user without self-hosting own GitLab instance.

Comment: I think that article _does_ mention such configuration, where it links to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/default.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe There is an option for an individual repo ("To update the default branch name for an individual project"), there is option for the entire instance or group ("GitLab administrators can configure"). I see nothing that would allow change for a given user without self-hosting own GitLab instance.

Comment: So doesn't that answer your question? If there was such an option, that's where it would be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Many projects and websites have poor documentation, hidden settings and other usability problems that still make possible that it is achievable. There are also sometime user-developed workarounds of various kinds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of april 2022 I believe this is not possible to configure. They seem to have baked the default branch name into the code.

Hopefully they will soon make this a setting that affects all new projects.

As a workaround I create a new project but do not tick the 'add readme' checkbox. The new project will be initialized without a branch.

Then I create the git project locally how I want it to be, add gitlab as remote and push it.

Seems to work:

[image: default branch name on gitlab after initial push]

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why they went with this ridiculous name changing. Are we about to rename "black hole", "dwarf planet", "master degree" etc?..

Answer (score 1):

I have a gitlab 15.3.1-ce server installed and the admin user can update the default branch name for all new projects.
In your browser go to this link (**replace 'myserver.gitlab.com' for your gitlab server name or IP**):
http://myserver.gitlab.com/admin/application_settings/repository#js-default-branch-name

**for secure configuration use https:**
https://myserver.gitlab.com/admin/application_settings/repository#js-default-branch-name

 You'll get this view:
[image]

Then, in the 'Initial Default Branch Name' field, type a new name (I used 'master') and click the Save Changes button.
Try to create a new project and check that your default branch name is as you set it.
[image]

Comment: There was " there is option for the entire instance or group ("GitLab administrators can configure").

I see nothing that would allow change for a given user without self-hosting own GitLab instance." but title was unclear. I will change it.